# What would you call a laugh that sounded like a mix between wheezing and a hiccup

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, vocabulary

A friend of mine suggested that one of her co-workers laughed in such a fashion, and I was curious if there was a single word or phrase that might closely resemble that.

I asked her if it sounded like a really creaky hiccup, and she said, "It sounds like he's having a little trouble breathing while he's laughing, and that it's punctuated by short hiccup noises."

I'd imagine the onomatopoeia would sound like "hyuk hyuk," but creaky sounding.

Answer (score 1):

There's **chortle**, a [portmanteau word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) defined as "laugh in a breathy, gleeful way" (Google) and coined by Lewis Carroll (probably as a mixture of "chuckle" and "snort").